# Is it worthwhile to post Udemy courses on your Developer Story?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

I was recently working on filling out my developer story, and I have taken a bunch of classes on Udemy since I worked on it last. However, I was unsure if it was a good idea to post those on there since employers look at that. Are Udemy courses seen as bad on a user's developer story? Or would it be a good idea to include those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a developer story like a resume.

If the course experience is more prevalent on your resume than either a degree or work experience, I don't see the harm in including it.

Otherwise, put it on there if you wish, but as a professional who participates in resume screens, the main thing I'd be looking for is if you meet the requirements for the job that we're hiring for.  **That** matters more, to me.